# Как сжать Bitmap?

Tags: java, android

Такая проблема...
У меня есть сохраненое фото на девайсе, мне его нужно показать юзеру в превью(чтоб он мог посмотреть). Использовать метод `setImageUri()` не получается так как пишет, что картинка большего размера, чем `ImageView` может принять.

Для этого я открываю файл, получаю байты и конвертирую их в битмап. И вот теперь у меня есть `Bitmap`, но как мне его сжать?

Примеры которые я нашел описывают ситуацию сжатия только когда мы пишем в файл так как для сжатия нужен `Outputstrem` , но я читал файл и у меня есть только `Inputstrem`.

**Подскажите как можно сжать изображение? Может его как то на уровне байтов сжать?**

Вот код

```
File file = new File(params[0]);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);


                long i = bis.read(bytes);

                System.out.println("Done !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " + i);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                    if (fis != null) {
                        fis.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
// Здесь нужно сжать битмап

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            if (image != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/catshop/bitmap.php) пишут, что можно сделать это методом `createScaledBitmap()` класса `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bmOriginal = ...;

// Вычисляем ширину и высоту изображения
int width = bmOriginal.getWidth();
int height = bmOriginal.getHeight();

// Половинки
int halfWidth = width / 2;
int halfHeight = height / 2;

// Выводим уменьшенную в два раза картинку в ImageView
Bitmap bmHalf = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmOriginal, halfWidth,
        halfHeight, false);
secondImageView.setImageBitmap(bmHalf);
```